# `cargo clippy` only produces output on the first run

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-clippy

I wanted to use Clippy to lint my code using Rust 1.31.1. I added a obvious mistake for the linker (and surely there is more to lint):

```
if (nr_children == 0) == true {...
```

I installed Clippy via rustup: `rustup component add clippy` (and *clippy-preview* as well).

When I run `cargo clippy`, I get no output, only `Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s` .

When I clean the build with `cargo clean` before calling Clippy, I get the lint warnings, but when I then re-run `cargo clippy`, nothing happens.
Even if I modify the code and save it before running `cargo clippy`, no output.
However, simply `touch`-ing the file, triggers Clippy to produce the linting.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?", you probably didn't change the good file or didn't save it properly.

Comment: @Stargateur Well, it was my first guess too, but saving the file causes a recompile by `cargo run` or `cargo build`

Comment: Btw: You don't need clippy-preview. Please remove that component, clippy is the new, stable component to add.